# Bracket notation dosent work for document.querySelector

Tags: javascript

I want to remove the third div element inside the body of the page by setting its style to `display:none;` and using `querySelector` with a bracket notation to get the element, but my code returns a error

> "TypeError: el is undefined"

and when I try to `console.log("el")` it returns `undefined`

I've tried using `let`, `const` except of `var` and some other things

```
var el = document.querySelector("div")[3]
el.style.display = "none"
```

It should remove the third div in the page.

Comment: `document.querySelector` returns a single node, to receive a node *list* you need to use `document.querySelectorAll()`

Comment: `querySelector()` will always give you just one result. What you want is `querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: Also, to get the 3rd element in the array, use `array[2]` because Javascript uses zero-based arrays.

Answer (score 3):

You're facing two issues:

- The [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method is for accessing a single DOM node. If you intend on working with more than one element, you can use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method which returns a node *list*
- The other issue is to remember that arrays use zero based numbering, meaning `[3]` accesses the fourth element, not the third. The count starts at zero.

With these two points in mind, what you're looking for is:

```
var el = document.querySelectorAll("div")[2]; // for the third div
el.style.display = "none";
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but why use querySelectorAll? i wanted to remove only the third div, and i forgot that JS starts counting from 0.

Comment: @Eperou: Because there is more than one div on the page. So if you only used `document.querySelector()` you're selecting only the first div that appears in your HTML. Since you want select from all divs (so you can select the third) you have to use `document.querySelectorAll()` which returns a node list of every div. Take a look at the links I provided in my answer for a better explanation.

Comment: Ohhh i get it now!

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to summarise @Sirko and @CoreyOgburn comments:

Don't use `document.querySelecto`r, it returns a `single node`, instead, use `document.getElementsbyTagName (my suggestion)` or stick with `document.querySelectorAll("div")`, which returns an `Array` of all div nodes on the site. Alternatively, use JQuery. And also, if you want to get the third element, you have to type `document.querySelectorAll("div")[2]`, not [3].